# Java: Expected a ',' or '}' at 43 [character 44 line 1] when parsing a json string with xml content

Tags: java, html, json

I'm using java to read 'xml' content, through API.

I have a sample page where I have the following code:

```
</form>
            <h2>Call service: <i>get_eD_XML</i></h2>
            <form action="get_eD_XML" method="POST">
                <input type='text' name='data'
                    value='{"eD_xml_data": "<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" classCode="DOCCLIN" moodCode="EVN" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 CDASchema/CDA_extended.xsd"><typeId extension="POCD_HD000040" root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3"/><templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.12559.11.10.1.3.1.1.2"/><templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.1.1"/><id extension="1551442190187" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.28284.6.2.4.104"/><code code="60593-1" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" codeSystemVersion="2.59" displayName="Medication dispensed.extended Document"><translation code="60593-1" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="eDispensation"/></code><title>Medication dispensed</title><effectiveTime value="20190301140950"/><confidentialityCode code="N" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.25" codeSystemName="Confidentiality" codeSystemVersion="913-20091020" displayName="normal"/><languageCode code="et-EE"/><setId extension="1551442190187" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.28284.6.2.4.104"/><recordTarget contextControlCode="OP" typeCode="RCT"><patientRole xmlns:epsos="urn:epsos-org:ep:medication"><id extension="100001" root="2.16.470.1.100.1.1.1000.990.1"/><addr><country>CY</country><streetAddressLine>11B Agiou Nikolaou, 1010, Dimes, Lemesos</streetAddressLine></addr><telecom use="H" value="tel:+99101002"/><telecom use="H" value="mailto:m.g@test.com"/><patient><name><given>Christoforou</given><family>Maria</family></name><administrativeGenderCode code="F" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1" codeSystemName="AdministrativeGender" codeSystemVersion="913-20091020" displayName="Female"><translation code="F" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1" codeSystemName="AdministrativeGender" displayName="Naine"><translation code="F" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1" codeSystemName="AdministrativeGender" displayName="Female"/></translation></administrativeGenderCode><birthTime value="19940421"/><languageCommunication><templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.2.1"/><languageCode code="en-GB"/></languageCommunication></patient></patientRole></recordTarget><author contextControlCode="OP" typeCode="AUT"><functionCode code="2262" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.2.9.6.2.7" codeSystemName="ISCO" codeSystemVersion="2008" displayName="Pharmacists"/><time value="20190301140950"/><assignedAuthor classCode="ASSIGNED"><id extension="48901112211" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.28284.6.2.4.9"/><addr><state nullFlavor="UNK"/><country>EE</country></addr><telecom nullFlavor="NI"/><assignedPerson classCode="PSN" determinerCode="INSTANCE"><name><family>Stupak</family><given>Aleksandra</given></name></assignedPerson><representedOrganization classCode="ORG" determinerCode="INSTANCE"><id extension="1.3.6.1.4.1.28284.4.74000091" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.28284.6.2.4.1"/><name>Eesti Haigekassa Haigekassa</name><telecom nullFlavor="NI"/><addr><streetAddressLine>Lastekodu tn 48</streetAddressLine><city>Tallinn Kesklinna linnaosa</city><postalCode nullFlavor="UNK"/><state nullFlavor="UNK"/><country>EE</country></addr></representedOrganization></assignedAuthor></author><custodian typeCode="CST"><assignedCustodian classCode="ASSIGNED"><representedCustodianOrganization classCode="ORG" determinerCode="INSTANCE"><id extension="70009770" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.28284.6.2.4.1"/><name>Tervise ja Heaolu Infosüsteemide Keskus</name><telecom use="WP" value="tel:+3726943943"/><addr><streetAddressLine>Uus-Tatari 25/Veerenni 13</streetAddressLine><city>Tallinn</city><postalCode>10134</postalCode><country>EE</country></addr></representedCustodianOrganization></assignedCustodian></custodian><legalAuthenticator typeCode="LA"><time value="20190301140950"/><signatureCode code="S"/><assignedEntity classCode="ASSIGNED"><id extension="70009770" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.28284.6.2.4.1"/><addr><state nullFlavor="UNK"/><country>EE</country></addr><telecom nullFlavor="NI"/><assignedPerson classCode="PSN" determinerCode="INSTANCE"><name><given>Vastutav</given><family>Isik</family></name></assignedPerson><representedOrganization classCode="ORG" determinerCode="INSTANCE"><id extension="70009770" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.28284.6.2.4.1"/><name>Tervise ja Heaolu Infosüsteemide Keskus</name><telecom use="WP" value="tel:+3726943943"/><addr><streetAddressLine>Uus-Tatari 25/Veerenni 13</streetAddressLine><city>Tallinn</city><postalCode>10134</postalCode><state nullFlavor="UNK"/><country>EE</country></addr></representedOrganization></assignedEntity></legalAuthenticator><inFulfillmentOf><order moodCode="RQO"><id extension="Prescriptions" root="2.16.620.1.101.10.3.29.54290"/></order></inFulfillmentOf><relatedDocument typeCode="XFRM"><parentDocument><id extension="1551442190187" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.28284.6.2.4.104"/></parentDocument></relatedDocument><component><structuredBody><component><section><templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.8"/><templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.12559.11.10.1.3.1.2.2"/><templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.9.1.2.3"/><id extension="1551442190187" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.28284.6.2.4.104"/><code code="60590-7" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" codeSystemVersion="2.59" displayName="Medication dispensed.brief Document"><translation code="60590-7" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="Medication dispensed"/></code><title>Medication dispensed</title><text><table><caption>Dispensed Items</caption><thead><tr styleCode="border-bottom: 2px solid black"><td>Identifier</td><td>Name</td><td>Strength</td><td>Form</td><td>Package</td><td>Package size</td><td>Number of packs</td><td>Note to patient</td><td>Note to pharmacist</td><td>Prescribed product</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1061288</td><td ID="dispensedProduct">LANTUS</td><td>100 [iU]/mL/ml</td><td>739</td><td>süstelahus</td><td>5 mL</td><td>10 {packages}</td><td ID="PINSTRUCT"/><td ID="FINSTRUCT"/><td ID="nameAsText">insulin glargine</td></tr></tbody></table></text><entry typeCode="COMP"><supply classCode="SPLY" moodCode="EVN"><templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.34"/><templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.4.7.3"/><templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.12559.11.10.1.3.1.3.3"/><id extension="1551442190187" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.28284.6.2.4.104"/><statusCode code="active"/><effectiveTime value="20190301140950"/><quantity unit="1" value="10"/><product><manufacturedProduct xmlns:epsos="urn:epsos-org:ep:medication" classCode="MANU"><templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.12559.11.10.1.3.1.3.1"/><templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.53"/><manufacturedMaterial classCode="MMAT" determinerCode="KIND"><epsos:id extension="1551442190187" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.28284.6.2.4.104"/><code code="1061288" codeSystem="1.3.6.1.4.1.28284.6.2.4.44" codeSystemName="Ravimpreparaadi kood" displayName="LANTUS"><originalText><reference value="#dispensedProduct"/></originalText></code><name>LANTUS</name><epsos:formCode code="11201000" codeSystem="0.4.0.127.0.16.1.1.2.1" codeSystemName="EDQM" codeSystemVersion="2017-04-14" displayName="Solution for injection"><epsos:translation code="739" codeSystem="1.3.6.1.4.1.28284.6.2.1.12" codeSystemName="Ravimvormid" displayName="süstelahus"/></epsos:formCode><epsos:asContent classCode="CONT"><epsos:containerPackagedMedicine classCode="CONT" determinerCode="INSTANCE"><epsos:name>LANTUS</epsos:name><epsos:formCode nullFlavor="NI"/><epsos:capacityQuantity unit="mL" value="5"/></epsos:containerPackagedMedicine></epsos:asContent><epsos:asSpecializedKind classCode="GEN"><epsos:generalizedMedicineClass classCode="MMAT"><epsos:code code="A10AE04" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.73" codeSystemName="Anatomical Therapeutic Chemical" codeSystemVersion="2017-01" displayName="insulin glargine"><epsos:translation code="A10AE04" codeSystem="1.3.6.1.4.1.28284.6.2.4.101" codeSystemName="Siseriiklik ATC" displayName="glargiin-insuliin"/></epsos:code><epsos:name>glargiin-insuliin</epsos:name></epsos:generalizedMedicineClass></epsos:asSpecializedKind><epsos:ingredient classCode="ACTI"><epsos:quantity><epsos:numerator unit="1{unit}" value="100" xsi:type="epsos:PQ"/><epsos:denominator unit="mL" value="1" xsi:type="epsos:PQ"/></epsos:quantity><epsos:ingredient classCode="MMAT" determinerCode="KIND"><epsos:code nullFlavor="UNK"/><epsos:name>Insulin glargine</epsos:name></epsos:ingredient></epsos:ingredient></manufacturedMaterial></manufacturedProduct></product><performer typeCode="PRF"><time value="20190301140950"/><assignedEntity><id extension="48901112211" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.28284.6.2.4.9"/><addr><state nullFlavor="UNK"/><country>EE</country></addr><telecom nullFlavor="NI"/><assignedPerson><name><family>Stupak</family><given>Aleksandra</given></name></assignedPerson><representedOrganization><id extension="1.3.6.1.4.1.28284.4.74000091" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.28284.6.2.4.1"/><name>Eesti Haigekassa Haigekassa</name><telecom nullFlavor="NI"/><addr><streetAddressLine>Lastekodu tn 48</streetAddressLine><city>Tallinn Kesklinna linnaosa</city><postalCode nullFlavor="UNK"/><state nullFlavor="UNK"/><country>EE</country></addr></representedOrganization></assignedEntity></performer><participant typeCode="PRF"><participantRole classCode="LIC"><scopingEntity classCode="ORG"><id root="1.3.6.1.4.1.28284"/><desc>TEHIK</desc></scopingEntity></participantRole></participant><entryRelationship typeCode="REFR"><templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.12559.11.10.1.3.1.3.2"/><substanceAdministration xmlns:epsos="urn:epsos-org:ep:medication" classCode="SBADM" moodCode="INT"><id extension="medicine.1" root="2.16.620.1.101.10.3.29.54290"/><statusCode code="active"/><effectiveTime xsi:type="IVL_TS"><low value="20190213"/><high value="20190414"/></effectiveTime><effectiveTime institutionSpecified="true" operator="A" xsi:type="PIVL_TS"><period nullFlavor="NA"/></effectiveTime><routeCode code="20066000" codeSystem="0.4.0.127.0.16.1.1.2.1" codeSystemName="EDQM" codeSystemVersion="2017-04-14" displayName="Subcutaneous use"><translation code="20066000" codeSystem="0.4.0.127.0.16.1.1.2.1" codeSystemName="EDQM" displayName="subkutaanne"><translation code="20066000" codeSystem="0.4.0.127.0.16.1.1.2.1" codeSystemName="EDQM" displayName="Subcutaneous use"/></translation></routeCode><doseQuantity nullFlavor="UNK"/><consumable typeCode="CSM"><manufacturedProduct classCode="MANU"><templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.12559.11.10.1.3.1.3.1"/><manufacturedMaterial classCode="MMAT" determinerCode="KIND"><code code="11201000" codeSystem="0.4.0.127.0.16.1.1.2.1" codeSystemName="EDQM" codeSystemVersion="2017-04-14" displayName="Solution for injection"/><name>insulin glargine</name><epsos:desc>100 [iU]/mL</epsos:desc><epsos:formCode code="11201000" codeSystem="0.4.0.127.0.16.1.1.2.1" codeSystemName="EDQM" codeSystemVersion="2017-04-14" displayName="süstelahus"><epsos:translation code="11201000" codeSystem="0.4.0.127.0.16.1.1.2.1" codeSystemName="EDQM" displayName="Solution for injection"/></epsos:formCode><epsos:asContent classCode="CONT"><epsos:containerPackagedMedicine classCode="CONT" determinerCode="INSTANCE"><epsos:name>LANTUS</epsos:name><epsos:formCode code="11201000" codeSystem="0.4.0.127.0.16.1.1.2.1" codeSystemName="EDQM" codeSystemVersion="2017-04-14" displayName="süstelahus"><epsos:translation code="11201000" codeSystem="0.4.0.127.0.16.1.1.2.1" codeSystemName="EDQM" displayName="Solution for injection"/></epsos:formCode><epsos:capacityQuantity unit="1" value="50"/><epsos:capTypeCode nullFlavor="NA"/></epsos:containerPackagedMedicine></epsos:asContent><epsos:asSpecializedKind classCode="GEN"><epsos:generalizedMedicineClass classCode="MMAT"><epsos:code code="A10AE04" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.73" codeSystemName="Anatomical Therapeutic Chemical" codeSystemVersion="2017-01" displayName="glargiin-insuliin"><epsos:translation code="A10AE04" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.73" codeSystemName="Anatomical Therapeutic Chemical" displayName="insulin glargine"/></epsos:code><epsos:name>insulin glargine, 100 [iU]/mL, 5 x 10 mL , Vial</epsos:name></epsos:generalizedMedicineClass></epsos:asSpecializedKind><epsos:ingredient xmlns="urn:epsos-org:ep:medication" classCode="ACTI"><epsos:quantity><epsos:numerator unit="[iU]/mL" value="100" xsi:type="epsos:PQ"/><epsos:denominator unit="mL" value="1" xsi:type="epsos:PQ"/></epsos:quantity><epsos:ingredient classCode="MMAT" determinerCode="KIND"><epsos:code code="A10AE04" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.73" codeSystemName="Anatomical Therapeutic Chemical" codeSystemVersion="2017-01" displayName="insulin glargine"/><epsos:name>LANTUS</epsos:name></epsos:ingredient></epsos:ingredient></manufacturedMaterial></manufacturedProduct></consumable><author><functionCode code="221" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.2.9.6.2.7" codeSystemName="ISCO" codeSystemVersion="2008" displayName="Medical doctors"><translation code="221" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.2.9.6.2.7" codeSystemName="ISCO" displayName="Arst"><translation code="221" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.2.9.6.2.7" codeSystemName="ISCO" displayName="Medical doctors"/></translation></functionCode><time value="2019021700+0200"/><assignedAuthor><id extension="654321" root="2.16.470.1.100.1.1.1000.990.1"/><addr><streetAddressLine>1 Hospital street</streetAddressLine><city>Nicosia</city><postalCode>1000</postalCode><country>CY</country></addr><telecom use="WP" value="tel:22111111"/><assignedPerson classCode="PSN" determinerCode="INSTANCE"><name><given>Marinos</given><family>Andreou</family></name></assignedPerson><representedOrganization><id extension="gov.cy" root="2.16.470.1.100.1.1.1000.990.1"/><name>Ministry of Health</name><telecom use="WP" value="tel:+22111111"/><telecom use="WP" value="mailto:test@ngh.com.cy"/><addr use="WP"><streetAddressLine>Hospital street, 121, 2222, Strovolos</streetAddressLine><state>UNK</state><country>CY</country></addr></representedOrganization></assignedAuthor></author><entryRelationship typeCode="COMP"><sequenceNumber value="1"/><supply classCode="SPLY" moodCode="RQO"><independentInd value="false"/><quantity unit="{packages}" value="5.0"/></supply></entryRelationship><entryRelationship inversionInd="true" typeCode="SUBJ"><observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN"><code code="SUBST" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.6" codeSystemName="ActClass" displayName="Substitution"/><value code="N" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1070" codeSystemName="SubstanceAdminSubstitution" codeSystemVersion="913-20091020" displayName="asendamine ei ole lubatud" xsi:type="CD"><translation code="N" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1070" codeSystemName="SubstanceAdminSubstitution" displayName="none"/></value></observation></entryRelationship></substanceAdministration></entryRelationship></supply></entry></section></component></structuredBody></component></ClinicalDocument>"}' />
                <input type="submit" value="Test" />
            </form>
```

I have the following java code to get the form's content:

```
JSONObject jsonData = null;
JSONObject search_data_obj = new JSONObject();

        try {

            if ((jsonData = new JSONObject(getJSONString(request))) != null) {
...//my code
}
```

However, when I try to push the submit button I get the following error:

```
org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at 43 [character 44 line 1].
```

The error occurs in `if ((jsonData = new JSONObject(getJSONString(request))) != null)`.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: That json value is not valid, the `"` are not escaped, e.g. `\"`

Comment: @Lino Thanks. The problem is that I will get the `xml` content in such a way. Is there a way to avoid this issue?

Comment: Receiving XML in JSON sounds weird. You normally choose for JSON so you don't have to deal with XML. The XML may be valid, but when you send it with JSON, you need to escape special characters: https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html